# What is a good explanation for the regexp object?

Tags: javascript, regex

as a newbie I'm trying to follow a codeacademy alternative solution for searching a string within a text block. Someone suggested using the regexp object:

```
var re = new RegExp(myName,'g');
```

The solution says this is equal to a regex e.g. /Wee Gillis/g

but when I then tried to log "re" to the console I don't see the regex, instead I see:

```
[object RegExp] {}
```

So what exactly is being created/instantiated here?

Comment: Try `console.log(re.source)`. Not sure if you need *that* though.

Comment: @Tushar and Caller: Do not agree with you: have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/toString) I also can not reproduce the situation in chrome..

Comment: @inetphantom, different browsers, different behaviour. I assume he's using some IE; this thing with `[object ... ]` sounds familiar. but that's off topic.

Comment: @Wiktor, jobe, `re.source` won't show the flags, better convert the regex to a string before logging. `re.toString()`, `String(re)`, `""+re`

Comment: @Thomas OP can see the flags, it is the pattern itself that is a variable. Anyway, the question is too unclear.

Comment: Hi @Thomas you gave the best answer, when I tried re.toString() - I was able to see the string version of the regular expression which is what I wanted to do.

Comment: Why did the question get downvoted? did I frame it badly? I couldn't find much help in a simple way online to understand this.

Comment: @Thomas not sure what you mean by using IE8 or different browsers but I was trying to run the code in codepen console which it turns out behaves differently to Chrome console which prints the regular expression when just using console.log(re).

Comment: The key question I wanted to understand is, isn't re a string regular expression when it's created? why did I have to use the toString method in order to display the regex - I didn't understand this. Thanks for all answers.

Comment: No, in JS, is there's a type for regular expressions, RegExp, wich is responsible for regex-related stuff. Every regex in JS is an instance of RegExp and has like Objects and Arrays also a way to write it as a literal, but can also be instantiated by its constructor.

Comment: @jobe, it's no big deal. instead of passing the source and the flags as Strings to the function, like you would in PHP, in JS there is a type to compose them. Another advantage is, that now you have a type you can check against -> you can easily tell a plain string and a regex apart. And the literal thing, well it's one of 3 types that have an alternative short notation to instantiate the most common use case for the particular type.

Comment: @jobe, the source is the part between the `/.../`, the flags are the part behind that. And the Literal part: you can write `var arr = [1,2,3]` or `var arr = new Array(3); arr[0]=1; arr[1]=2; arr[2]=3;` you can write `var obj = { foo: 42 }` or `var obj = new Object(); obj.foo = 42;` and you can write `var regex = /^\/foo/gi` or `var regex = new RegExp("^\\/foo", "gi")` this is the difference between using a literal and using the constructor; but the result is always the same, an instance of the particular type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121962/discussion-between-j-obe-and-thomas).

Answer (score -2):

The object you are getting is described in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

It has no public attributes but functions.

```js
    var re = new RegExp("j obe",'g');

        console.log(re);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(re));
```